# WordPress metabox - div editable as input

Tags: wordpress

I created a WordPress metabox of a custom post type (`'inventaire'`). I would like to create an `inv_content` taxonomy that is contained in an editable div (because it is to make tables and edit them instantly).

I have the impression, however, that WordPress does not accept div editable entries, because in my post saving function, `$_POST['inv_content']` does not exist.

Is that the problem? I tried with `<input type='text'>` but it does not render HTML content (for a table content, it is not practical). How could I do that?

```
function inventaire_add_metabox_table() {
    add_meta_box(
        'metabox_table',        
        'Contenu',                
        'show_metabox_table',   
        'inventaire',           
        'normal',              
        'high'                  
    );
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'inventaire_add_metabox_table');

function show_metabox_table() {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field( 'inventaire_add_metabox_table_nonce', 'inventaire_add_table_nonce' ); 

    $table = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'inv_content', true);

?>
    <div id="inv-div-content" class="div_content inside" name="inv_content" contenteditable="true">
<?php 
}

function inventaire_save_metabox_table( ) {
    global $post;

    if( !isset( $_POST['inventaire_add_table_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['inventaire_add_table_nonce'],'inventaire_add_metabox_table_nonce') ) 
        return;

        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )) 
        return;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;

    $meta_key = 'inv_content';
    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST[$meta_key] ) ?  $_POST[$meta_key] : '' );
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true);

    var_dump( $_POST[$meta_key]);

    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value ){
        add_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, $new_meta_value, true); 
        echo 'add';
    }

    elseif ( $new_meta_value && $new_meta_value != $meta_value ){
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );
        echo 'update';
    }

    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value ){
        delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, $meta_value );
        echo 'delete';
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'inventaire_save_metabox_table' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create div with `contenteditable="true"` attribute, and in javascript, add event listener for this element:

```js
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("inv-div-content").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
   var inputContent = e.target.innerHTML; //do whatever you want with value
    document.getElementById('actual-content-to-send').value = inputContent;
}, false);
}
```

```css
#inv-div-content{
width: 60%;
height: 50px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div contenteditable="true" id="inv-div-content" >Insert your text content</div> <br>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="6" id="actual-content-to-send" name="user_typed_content" disabled></textarea>  <br>
note: change this text area to input element of hidden type, I have set to text to see it working
```

See more about `contenteditable`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

and more about `input` event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Change text area to input of hidden type:

Comment: Does `textarea` has a hidden type? It does not seem to work

Comment: no, you need to change it to `<input type="hidden"/>` I have just  set this as sample

Comment: that is basics HTML

Comment: yes , just wanted to use JQuery and I'm doing the data transfer (between the div to the input) at the click of the `#publish`

Answer (score 2):

**Two options:**

**1.**

Add an input type hidden and update its value with javascript when the contenteditable div has changed. Set its value as contentEditable content.

**2**

Replace

```
<div id="inv-div-content" class="div_content inside" name="inv_content" contenteditable="true">
```

by

```
<textarea id="inv-div-content" class="div_content inside" name="inv_content">
```

Comment: `textarea` does not render HTML as well. I'm trying the first option, thanks!